# How can one buy/obtain Microsoft DVD/CD media when you have download only version MSDNAA

Tags: msdn

As the title says, how can one buy Microsoft CD/DVDs, if one already has a legitimate licence key for the product?

Incidentally, it is not that I have lost the CDs, it is that I am member of MSDNAA Developer program, which provides Computer Science students with certain Microsoft titles. I have the licence keys and burnt media(as sanctioned by Microsoft), but it does not feel substantial enough. Silly feeling, I guess.

I would love to pay to obtain actual physical media with box and everything(green earth issues put aside for the moment).

For some reason, I remember that a few years back one could buy replacement Windows Xp disks from Microsoft. Any similar programs still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media shipped from MS on this program is usually contained in a plastic sleeve, not a box.  Burned media will be about the same without the nice label. As Chris F mentioned, your burned copy should be fine. And you can always burn another!

Comment: Ahh, if no boxed media, guess I will resort to making nifty labels myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could always burn the .iso image you downloaded to DVD - I know it's not the same as having a pressed DVD, but it should last long enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading your subscription to "Online + Media" would be a reasonable price to pay if you would like to receive boxed and pressed media from Microsoft.

on the other hand, you can always burn a new disc, if you stash away the images, the price for hard disk space is at an all time low. :)

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, although not sure, if I can upgrade the program, if it goes through University(I am not an administrator).